# MongoDB nested Query Structure

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following json document in my collection :

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "59e3a593734d1d62dcbe79c3"
    }
    "name": "UserNameKiran"
    "notebooks": [
        {
            "notebookname": "notebook1",
            "notes": [
                {
                    "name": "noteName"
                },
                {
                    "name": "noteName2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "access": "public",
            "notebookname": "notebook2",
            "notes": [
                {
                    "name": "noteName"
                },
                {
                    "name": "noteName2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

I want to retrieve all the "notes" from a particular user and notebook.
Ex: all the notes for "notebook1".

I tried the following command but was not able to get any result.

```
 req.db.collection('usernotecollection').find({
      "_id": ObjectId(req.params.userId),
      "notebooks": {
          "$elemMatch": {
              "notebookname": "notebook1"
          }
      }
    }, {notes:1}).toArray(function (err, results) {
        console.log(results);
  });
```

It is just returning me the object_id and nothing else in the results. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter you are providing to the `find()` call is: `{notes:1}`.

This is a projection, it tells MongoDB to return the attribute named `notes` but there is **no** attribute named `notes` in your document so the projection only returns the default attribute: `_id`.

Perhaps you meant to project on `{notebooks:1}` instead? Though this would return everything and is therefore functionally equivalent to providing no projection.

To make this clear, you could run the following commands and you'll see that they both return the same response:

```
 req.db.collection('usernotecollection').find({
      "_id": ObjectId(req.params.userId),
      "notebooks": {
          "$elemMatch": {
              "notebookname": "notebook1"
          }
      }
    }).toArray(function (err, results) {
        console.log(results);
  });

 req.db.collection('usernotecollection').find({
      "_id": ObjectId(req.params.userId),
      "notebooks": {
          "$elemMatch": {
              "notebookname": "notebook1"
          }
      }
    }, {notebooks:1}).toArray(function (err, results) {
        console.log(results);
  });
```

If, however, what you actually want is the `notes` attribute with the `notebooks` sub documents then you'll want to project on `'notebooks.notes': 1`. The following example projects on `notebooks.notes` and excludes the default `_id` projection thereby only returning `notebooks.notes`:

```
 req.db.collection('usernotecollection').find({
      "_id": ObjectId(req.params.userId),
      "notebooks": {
          "$elemMatch": {
              "notebookname": "notebook1"
          }
      }
    }, {'notebooks.notes':1, '_id': 0}).toArray(function (err, results) {
        console.log(results);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. However, I am not able to get the notes of a specific notebook. For some reason, the match for "notebookname": "notebook1" is not happening.

Comment: Tehre is no attribute in the `notebooks` sub document named `notebookname` perhaps you mean `notes.name`. In general, questions of this form (_how can I get x out of this document?_) are best asked with (1) a sample document; (2) an example of the query you have tried and (3) **the desired output**.

Answer (score 0):

In order to filter the array elements you can use the [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) operator in the projection part of your query.

```
req.db.collection('usernotecollection').find({
    // filter
    "_id": ObjectId(req.params.userId)
}, {
    // projection
    "notebooks": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "notebookname": "notebook1"
        }
    }
}).toArray(function (err, results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```